# Flask: Nothing matches the given URI

Tags: python, python-2.7, http, flask, request

I'm trying to upload a file using Flask.
Here is my HTML code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Python Starter Application</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/upload">
        File input
        <input type="file" name="InputFile">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Upload</button>
    </form> 
</body>
</html>
```

here is my flask code

```flask
import os
from flask import Flask, request
import swiftclient

try:
    from SimpleHTTPServer import SimpleHTTPRequestHandler as Handler
    from SocketServer import TCPServer as Server
except ImportError:
    from http.server import SimpleHTTPRequestHandler as Handler
    from http.server import HTTPServer as Server

app = Flask(__name__)
# Read port selected by the cloud for our application
PORT = int(os.getenv('PORT', 8000))
# Change current directory to avoid exposure of control files
os.chdir('static')

httpd = Server(("", PORT), Handler)

# connections
auth_url = ##
project = ##
projectId = ##
region = ##
userId = ##
username = ##
password = ##
domainId = ##
domainName = ##
container_name = ##

conn = swiftclient.Connection(key=password,
                              authurl=auth_url,
                              auth_version='3',
                              os_options={"project_id": projectId,
                                          "user_id": userId,
                                          "region_name": region})

@app.route('/upload', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    file = request.files['InputFile']
    file_name = file.filename
    conn.put_object(container_name,
                    file_name,
                    contents=file_name.read(),
                    content_length=1024)
    return '''
    <html>
    <title>Upload new File</title>
    <body>
    <h1>Successful</h1>
    </body>
    </html>
    '''

try:
    print("Start serving at port %i" % PORT)
    httpd.serve_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
httpd.server_close()
```

Am I missing something?
I still get

> Error response Error code 404. Message: File not found. Error code explanation: 404 = Nothing matches the given URI.

Comment: in your form tag, give action="" and try again e.g <form action="" method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>

Comment: It still give me the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like you are using flask i think that the best solution would be a flask solution like:

```
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # check if the post request has the file part
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            flash('No file part')
            return redirect(request.url)
        file = request.files['file']
        # if user does not select file, browser also
        # submit a empty part without filename
        if file.filename == '':
            flash('No selected file')
            return redirect(request.url)
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            #return to the file or what do you want
            return redirect(url_for('uploaded_file',
                                    filename=filename))
```